# AWS CDK Pipeline deployment fails - Cannot create AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy an AWS CDK Pipeline into a personal AWS account. I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html).

I get the following error:

```
19:38:51 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline | MyPipeline92D3D757
Internal Failure
```

This error is also seen in AWS CloudFormation, when I look at the Stack, it says it failed at creating the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused because the AWS CodePipeline could not authenticate with my (personal) Github account. The AWS CodePipeline is needed when creating a CDK pipeline.

I had defined my Pipeline to read the source code from my Github account:

```js
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'MyPipeline', {
  pipelineName: 'MyPipeline',
  synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
    input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub('DanielApt/iamapt-cdk', 'main'),
    commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth']
  })
});
```

The Pipeline could not be created, because my AWS account could not authenticate with my Github account. AWS uses a secret stored in AWS Secrets Manager, called `github-token`.

I did not have this, so I created the `github-token` as follows:

1. [Create a Github personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new) - [see documentation to learn more](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) .

- Make sure it has the `repo` and `admin:repo_hook` scopes selected.

2. Store it in AWS Secrets Manager. The secret's value should be the access token, and the secret name must be `github-token`